# Jquery get domain name from url and check that domain name exist in an array that i have already

Tags: jquery, validation, url, dns

I have a input field with submit button. When user enter any url in that field and click on submit i have to check

1. is it a valid url and
2. i have an array of domian names and i have to check the entered url is from the domain names that i already have.

Here is my HTML

```
<input type="text" id="product_url" placeholder="Enter product's full url">
<button type="button" id="validate_url">Validate URL</button>
```

this is array of domains that i have in jquery

```
  var testCases  = ["corsair.com","oculus.com","rcplanet.com","irobot","store.hp.com"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this ?

Comment: You have been a member for over a year - you really should know [ask]. Please next time create a [mcve] with what you have tried.

Comment: as i am new to jquery so i did little bit research and couldn't found anything useful so i posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code using URL

```js
var testCases = ["amazon.com","corsair.com", "oculus.com", "rcplanet.com", "irobot", "store.hp.com"]
$(function() {
  $("#validate_url").on("click", function() {
    var found = "", val = $(this).prev().val();
    try {
      var url = new URL(val);
      $.each(testCases, function(_, part) {
        if (url.hostname.indexOf(part) != -1) {
          found=part;
          return false; // leave the loop
        }
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
    if (found) console.log("found",found)
    else console.log(val,"not found")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="product_url" placeholder="Enter product's full url">
<button type="button" id="validate_url">Validate URL</button>
```

Comment: HI thank
but i am getting this error
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
and 
Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: Using which URL? - When new URL gives error it is not a valid URL

Comment: I added a try/catch

Comment: `https://www.amazon.com/` works just fine - no message because it is not in the array - now it is

Comment: anyways i get the url value by $('#product_url').val(); but after that i am getting this error Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
can you please help me with that

Comment: Why do I have to guess at your HTML - please create a [mcve] by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52809874/edit) and then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and add HTML and code

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```js
function isUrlValid(url) {
  return /^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900- \uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(url);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#ValidateURL", function() {
    var URL = $("#URL").val();
    var testCases = ["corsair.com", "oculus.com", "rcplanet.com", "irobot", "store.hp.com"]
    if (testCases.indexOf(URL) > -1) {
      if (isUrlValid('http://' + URL)) {
        console.log("URL found and valid URL");
      } else {
        console.log("URL found but invalid URL");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("URL not found");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="URL" />
<button id="ValidateURL">Validate URL</button>
```

Comment: This will not work. Did you try? The bits of URL in the array are not fully formed - the regex gives error too

Comment: copy code and paste on Notepad++ file with jquery library and then check .. it will work 100%.

Comment: Also no need for a regex when new URL will test the validity. `corsair.com` is not a valid URL